# Woocommerce: How to allow only one product type in a cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I have two product types, one of them simple product `$cart_item['default-engraving']` and the other one credit product `$cart_item['default-engraving'] && $cart_item['iconic-engraving']`. I'm trying to find a solution how to make that if I add simple product to a cart, credit product shouldn't be added. Or if I add credit product to a cart, simple product should't be added. But if I want I could add same type for example simple product type as many as I want.

Comment: I have improved formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Is not possible to detect custom cart item data on add to cart event.

Checking cart items will allow you to prevent having cart items that have `$cart_item['default-engraving']` and `$cart_item['iconic-engraving']` at the same time:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_cart_items_custom_data' );
function check_cart_items_custom_data() {
    // Initializing: set the current product type in an array
    $types = [];

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        if( isset( $item['default-engraving'] ) )
            $types[] = 'default';

        if( isset( $item['iconic-engraving'] ) )
            $types[] = 'iconic';
    }

    $types = array_unique( $types );

    // Check the number of product types allowing only one
    if( count( $types ) > 1 ){

        // Displaying a custom notice and avoid checkout
        wc_add_notice( __('Only items from one product type are allowed in cart'), 'error' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

---

**Original answer**: *(it can't work for your case as it's not possible to detect that on add to cart event)*

Here is the way targeting the product type to allow only one in cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_one_product_type_allowed', 10, 3 );
function only_one_product_type_allowed( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    // Initializing: set the current product type in an array
    $types = [ wc_get_product( $product_id )->get_type() ];

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        // Set each product type in the array
        $types[] = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] )->get_type();
    }

    $types = array_unique( $types );

    // Check the number of product types allowing only one
    if( count( $types ) > 1 ){

        // Displaying a custom notice
        wc_add_notice( __('Only items from one product type are allowed in cart'), 'error' );
        return false; // Avoid add to cart
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Related: [Allow only one product category in cart at once in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523582/allow-only-one-product-category-in-cart-at-once-in-woocommerce/52524024#52524024)

Comment: Thanks for response but I've two product type, one of them is iconic(I added some information about credit) other one is simple product. I need to add them separately in a cart but as many as customer wants to buy. Every products are simple product in a beginning but if you choose some iconic option (credit option) it changes to iconic and cares some extra information and it changes, for example to downloadable product (custom product). So this custom product should't be in a cart with normal product or reverse normal product  should't be with a iconic product in a cart.

Comment: @ShamsMamadjonov I have updated my answer… As explained, is not possible to detect custom cart item data on add to cart event, so the only way is to prevent checkout in your case…

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_one_product_category_allowed', 20, 3 );
function only_one_product_category_allowed( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {

    // Getting the product categories term slugs in an array for the current product
    $term_slugs   = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'slugs') );

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){

        // Check if the product category of the current product don't match with a cart item

        $_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id']; );
if( $_product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
// code to not allow other product type
} else {
// do stuff for everything else
}
    }
}
```

Comment: you missed one closing }, and while I added code to a project it is not allowing me to add any product to a cart.

Answer (score 0):

please check below code.

```
<?php
function ji_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) 
{
        $_product =  wc_get_product( $product_id);      
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
            $checkTypes[] = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] )->get_type();
        }
        $checkTypes = array_unique( $types );

        if(count($checkTypes) > 0)
        {
            if(!in_array($_product->get_type(),$checkTypes))
            {
            wc_add_notice( __('Here you can add your error message','textdomain'), 'error' );
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'ji_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
?>
```