# Only allow one child category in cart at a time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following as one of my product categories:

Category A

- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3

Each child has multiple products. I would like to make it so only one child category can be in the cart at once, but, I want all the products within that child category to be able to be added.

I have tried modifying the [Allow only one product category in cart at once in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523582/allow-only-one-product-category-in-cart-at-once-in-woocommerce/52524024#52524024) answer by adding a query for the children of category A, but it isn't working, and is preventing me from adding items from the same child category to the cart.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_checking_product_added_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function custom_checking_product_added_to_cart( $passed, $product_id) {


    // Child Query
    
    $term_id       = get_term_by( 'slug', 'category-A', 'product_cat' );
    $taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
    $termchildren  = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    
    // if the product is in Category A
    if ( has_term( 'category-A', 'product_cat', $product_id )  ) {
        // Iterating through each cart item
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            
             if( ! has_term( $termchildren, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                // Don't add 
                $passed = false;
                
                // Displaying a message
                wc_add_notice( 'Only one product from a category is allowed in cart', 'error' );

                // We stop the loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
```